# How can I extract the text of multiple URLs with lynx/w3m in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe, lynx

I have made a list of 50 odd URLs in one text file (one URL per each line). Now, for each URL I want to extract the text of the web site and save it down. This sounds like a job for a shell script in Linux.

At the moment I am putting things together:

1. with say `sed -n 1p listofurls.txt` I could read the first line in my URL file, `listofurls.txt`
2. with `lynx -dump www.firsturl...` I can use the output for piping through various commands to tidy and clean it up. Done, that works.

Before automating, I am struggling to piping in the URLs into lynx: say

```
sed -n 1p listofurls.txt | lynx -dump -stdin
```

does not work.

How can I do that say for one URL, and more importantly for each URL I have in `listofurls.txt`?

Comment: Why not use `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: I think you want `sed -n 1p listofurls.txt | xargs lynx -dump` OR `awk '{ print $0 }' listofurls.txt |  xargs lynx -dump`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write script like this

```
vi script.sh

#content of script.sh#
while read line
do
    name=$line
    wget $name
    echo "Downloaded content from - $name"
done < $1
#end#

chmod 777 script.sh

./script.sh listofurls.txt
```

Comment: `777` permissions set global read, write, and execute permissions, and is generally considered extremely bad practise. In this case, all you need to do is `chmod +x script.sh`.

Comment: @pgl: User can what ever permission they want to set

Comment: Well, sure, technically it's possible. But that's like saying users can set their password to "password" if they want - it's still not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

To pipe one URL to lynx, you can can use `xargs`:

```
sed -n 1p listofurls.txt | xargs lynx -dump
```

To download all URLs from the file (parse them by lynx and just print out), you can do:

```
while read url; do lynx - -dump $url; done < listofurls.txt
```